# passing custom variable into Command with xamarin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

i want to pass a list of ints (called buy_player_unit) into my buy unit function from a button on my mainpage.xaml. i thought i could use Commandparameters... but now im not sure.

unit_view_model.cs

```
namespace top_down_rts
{
    public class units_view_model
    {

        public ObservableCollection<unit> Unit_list { get; set; }
        public player player_inst { get; set; }
        
        public units_view_model()
        {
            this.Unit_list = new ObservableCollection<unit>();
            this.player_inst = new player();
        }

        public ICommand buy_unit_command => new Command(buy_unit);
        void buy_unit(object parameter)
        {
       // i want this function to recieve the buy_player_unit object
            Console.WriteLine("buy");
            var values = (object[])parameter;
            int x = (int)values[0];
            int y = (int)values[1];
            int team = (int)values[2];
            int price = (int)values[3];

            Console.WriteLine(this.player_inst.money);
            this.player_inst.money -= price;
            Unit_list.Add(new unit(x, y, team));  
        }

        public object buy_player_unit()
        {
     // i want to push this into the buy_unit function
            return new object[] { 50, 50, 0, 1 };
        }


    }
}
```

below is my xml

mainpage.xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:top_down_rts"
             x:Class="top_down_rts.MainPage">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:units_view_model/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>

    <StackLayout>

        <Button 
            HorizontalOptions="Start" 
            WidthRequest="200" 
            Text="buy" 
            Command="{Binding buy_unit_command}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding buy_player_unit}"
                />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

but i get this error

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

on this line

```
int x = (int)values[0];
```

so i think this line

```
CommandParameter="{Binding buy_player_unit}"
```

is not passing in my object like i hope.

why doesnt it work? am i missunderstanding something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CommandParameter` expects property, not a method. And your binded `buy_player_unit` value is a method `buy_player_unit()`.

Try to replace it with property

```
    public object buy_player_unit =>
        new object[] { 50, 50, 0, 1 };
```

Or dynamically calculated:

```
    public object buy_player_unit => GetPlayerUnit();
```

By the way, why can't you just use `buy_player_unit` directly in the view model? Without passing it through the long chain VM-View via binding-VM via command parameter.

From your example it looks like that you can remove `ComandParameter` and then access  `buy_player_unit`  directly from within `buy_unit_command`, without the parameter.